# Creating a blank file from a batch file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I would like create a file from a batch file. I can use the `echo. > donald.txt`, but it creates it with an initial blank line. What else I can use to a file starting from the first line?

Comment: Still a bit confused on what the problem is? Starting from the first line...can you clarify that?

Comment: To aid future searches, **empty file** is synonymous with **blank file**.

Comment: I don't think so. An **empty file** contains 0 bytes, but a **blank file** contains a certain number of spaces or lines with spaces. I think the OP should rename the question title and change "blank" by "empty".

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You just want to create a completely empty file?  This will do it:

```
copy /y nul donald.txt
```

If you're looking to write something to first line, you want something like this:

```
echo Hello, World > donald.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

One of the options is

```
@echo off
rem Don't destroy an existing file
if exist testfile goto _nocreate
:: Create the zero-byte file
type nul>testfile
:_nocreate
```

Originally from http://www.netikka.net/tsneti/info/tscmd041.htm which contains some additional methods.

Answer (score 1):

In old MS-DOS days I used this method to create an empty file:

```
rem > empty.txt
```

In new Windows this no longer works, but `rem` may be replaced by any command that show nothing. For example:

```
cd . > empty.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PowerShell:

```
function touch {set-content -Path ($args[0]) -Value ($null) } 
touch file-name
```

Source: http://blog.lab49.com/archives/249.

Comment: Urgh, that's an evil way of defining a `touch` command. Remember that `touch` is not only used for creating empty files, but also for updating the timestamp of an existing one. Better not use a name that has multiple uses already ;-). In keeping with PowerShell terminology, this should *probably* be called `New-Item`. But wait ... that already exists. `New-Item foo.txt -Type File` (or `ni -t f foo.txt` if you like it shorter). So, this is probably a non-solution to something that can be done easier with the tools already there.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `echo.` inserts a blank line in your file.

Try using the same code, but without the period appended to the end of the `echo` statement:

```
echo "Test string" > donald.txt
```

Comment: If they want an empty file, then they certainly don't want the file to read "Test string" (even including the quotation marks).

Comment: @Joey: I interpreted "What else I can use to a file starting from the first line?" as meaning they wanted to write text into the file, but they wanted it to appear on the first line of the file, rather than the second with a blank line at the top.

Comment: Ah, ok. The question was indeed a little murky.